# Joomla 3.10.x SQL Injection XSS Vulnerability

Tags: joomla-3.x, security

I have a website setup on my infrastructure that is running Joomla 3.10.8. During a security audit, certain SQL injection vulnerabilities / XSS have been identified.

The setup includes a bunch of plugins like K2 for managing the display of content and workflows. As there has been no custom development of any of these components, how do I address this security issue?

Are there any recommendations or best practices that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the security extension https://securitycheck.protegetuordenador.com/subscriptions. Awesome extension with great features and great pro-active support. I recommend this to anyone who wants to secure their joomla site with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

If the vulnerability is indeed in core Joomla and not in one of the installed extensions you can contact the Joomla Security Strike Team via this page
https://developer.joomla.org/security.html